# Preencher multiplos html input com informação de tabela

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho uma JSP com tabela com várias linhas e duas colunas. Tenho dez linhas de input onde quero jogar célula 0 e célula 1 no item1 e no descr1 do primeiro input. Ao clicar na próxima linha da tabela quero jogar célula0 e célula1 no item2 e no descr2 do segundo input e assim sucessivamente. Só que a mesma linha da tabela está sendo carregada no primeiro e no segundo input ou seja item1 descr1 e item2 e descr2.

````
        {
            linha = 1;
            let tabela = document.getElementById("tabprd");
            
            if(tabela != null)
            {
                for(let i = 0; i < tabela.rows.length; i++)               
                {
                   tabela.rows[i].onclick = 
                        function()
                        {
                            if(linha === 1)
                            {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                document.getElementById("item1").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                document.getElementById("descr1").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                linha++;
                            }
                        
                            if(linha === 2)
                            {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                document.getElementById("item2").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                document.getElementById("descr2").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                linha++;
                            }                         
                        };
                }
            }
        }```
Esse é o javascript que uso para o load.
Atenciosamente,
Cezar Apulchro.
````

Answer (score 0):

Galera problema resolvido, nada com pesquisar e estudar um pouco mais.
Minha solução:

````
        function loadCell()
        {
            
            let tabela = document.getElementById("tabprd");
            
            if(tabela != null)
            {
                for(let i = 0; i < tabela.rows.length; i++)               
                {
                   tabela.rows[i].onclick = 
                        function()
                        {
                            if(linha === 1)
                            {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                document.getElementById("item1").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                document.getElementById("descr1").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                linha++;
                                return linha;
                            }
                            else
                                if(linha === 2)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item2").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr2").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 3)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item3").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr3").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 4)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item4").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr4").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 5)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item5").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr5").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 6)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item6").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr6").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 7)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item7").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr7").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 8)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item8").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr8").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 9)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item9").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr9").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                            else
                                if(linha === 10)
                                {alert("linha: " + linha);
                                    document.getElementById("item10").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                                    document.getElementById("descr10").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                                    linha++;
                                    return linha;
                                }                         
                        };
                }
            }
        }
        ```
Obrigado.
````